# Creating linkedlist in JAVA

Tags: java, list, linked-list

It seems that there are some differences between the following statement:

```
LinkedList<String> res = new LinkedList<>();

List<String> res = new LinkedList<>();
```

Because when I use the function `res.peek()`, there is an error of the second statement. It said that `res.peek()` could not be found. But the first statement turned to be right.

Could anyone explain why this could happen?

Comment: We would need to see the actual code. Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList is the class and it has the method peek() and when you use List i.e. interface it does not have the method peek(). That's why it works like this.

[LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

[List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

The reason is the parent class or the implemented interface does not have the properties of its child class.

1)`LinkedList res = new LinkedList<>();`
Here reference variable is of **LinkedList** which has the `peek()` method.

2)`List res = new LinkedList<>();`
Here reference variable is of **List** which does not have the `peek()` method.

Hope this helps :)